# Anonymous namespace to include a function in two cpp files

Tags: c++

I have a function which should be included in two different translation units (i.e. cpp files) from a common header.

I might use an anonymous namespace to have this function included in both TUs without conflicts but I'm wondering what would be the best way to accomplish this (static? I don't think global could work, multiple definitions)

Comment: If you want to add definition of a function in header file then using `inline` is the right approach.

Comment: But those are long functions, does that make sense?

Comment: @DavidKernin: `inline` has very little to do with function inlining, so  the length of the function doesn't matter. Consider it misnamed if it helps. `inline` ensures the condition required for compile-time function inlining (that the definition of the function is available in the TU), so its *real* meaning is to indicate a function whose definition is available in every TU that includes the header. The compiler decides what to actually inline based on its own heuristics, that may or may not depend on whether you marked it `inline`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to be the same function in every TU, use `inline`. That's exactly what `inline` is for: shared functions defined in headers.

In the admittedly-unlikely event that you want it to be a different function in every TU, use either an unnamed namespace or `static`. I don't think the standard gives an official view which one is preferred in C++, but you kind of get the impression it's the unnamed namespace.

Which one you want depends on why you're putting a function definition in a header file in the first place, and how you intend the header to be used.

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn the difference between declaration of function and it's definition. Except of template and inline functions only function declaration should be in a header file, function definition should be in translation unit.

```
void foobar( int ); // this is function declaration, now you can call this function
                    // you can put it on your sources as many times as you want

void foobar( int param ) { // this is function definition, it should appear only once
   ...
}
```

Comment: "except... " and `static` non-member functions. And functions in nameless namespaces. Quite a lot of things, really :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop I think to put `static` non-member or nameless namespace function into a header is hmm strange at least. What would be the purpose?

Comment: For example, it allows you to link together different TUs that use the same header but with different -D options that affect the definition of the function. You can't use `inline` in such circumstances since the different definitions would violate the ODR.

Comment: @SteveJessop yea possible, but I would kill somebody on my team trying to do this crap on the first code review. Way to disaster.

Comment: Your loss, but since you're in charge of the style guide you can set any rules you like. The point isn't so much that you *want* to set different behaviour via #defines, it's that you don't want to have to bother tracking whether every TU (possibly including libraries compiled as separate projects) uses the same options or not.

Comment: @SteveJessop there are exceptions for every rule, but I would not recommend to use this "technique" in production code, especially for beginners. In my answer I said "should be" not "must be", so you if you understand what you are doing, go ahead. To give that as recommendation, no thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want that the compiler would consider this function as a different function in each CU you can include its definition in an unnamed namespace. According to the C++ 2011 Standard entities declared in unnamed namespaces have internal linkage.